# How to force evaluation of lazy seqs in Clojure when running from an uberjar?

Tags: clojure, lazy-sequences, uberjar

Consider the following MWE:

```
(ns toto.core
(:gen-class))

(defn write-something [i]
  (spit (str "out-" (str i) ".txt") "Hi there!"))

(defn -main
  "I don't do a whole lot ... yet."
  [& args]
  (dorun (pmap write-something (range 16))))
```

If I run `-main` from the REPL, it works as expected: it creates the files and returns. However, if I create an uberjar and run `java -jar <toto.whatever-standalone.jar>` it will create the files, but fail to exit the program. I suspect it is an issue with laziness, but can't figure why the `dorun` is not working as I'd expect. 
 Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: It doesn't look like a laziness issue. If all files were created, then lazy sequence was realized.

Comment: dorun walks through the successive nexts of the seq in any case so what is the fail message you get?

Comment: There's no error message, it's just that the `java -jar ...` call never returns.

Comment: Leonid, you are right, the seqs were realized. Yet, the application doesn't return from main...

Comment: @mvarela could you provide additional information about your environment: os type and version, `java`, `clojure` and `lein` versions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Clojure the [pmap](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/pmap) function uses [future](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/future) calls that utilize a common thread pool. The threads in the pool stay alive for a 1 minute after they have finished their tasks in order to reduce the cost of thread allocation.

If you are sure that the thread pool can be shut down (because the application quits) you need to call 
[shutdown-agents](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/shutdown-agents) after the `(dorun ...)` so the thread pool is killed.

Alternatively, you can call `(System/exit <status>)` to shut down the application instantly.

Comment: Thanks! the `shutdown-agents` call did the trick.